# merge object and objects inside array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, functional-programming

The original data are like this

```
var d = {A1:{name:"A1",value:10}, A2:{name:"A2",value:8}}
var l = [{name: "A1", 1min: 1, 2min:10}, {name: "A2", 1min:5, 2min:40}}
```

What I need to do is merge `d` and `l` together for the same `name`, the result would be like this:

```
{A1: {name:"A1", value:10, 1min: 1, 2min:10}, 
 A2: {name: "A2", value:8, 1min:5, 2min:40}}
```

I think `if` and `loop` may help me work it out. But for very large dataset, is there a better and easier way to do this?

Comment: Do the properties and `name`s always match in `d`? So that `d[key].name === key;`?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yes, they always match

Comment: This question has nothing to do with d3. You are probably using this array as a node list for a d3 graph, but this has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
for (var i=0; i < l.length; ++i) {
    var tmp = l[i];

    for (var key in tmp) {
        d[ tmp.name ][ key ] = tmp[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: You actually don´t need to delete the name as it will be overriden with the same value.